# Remove previous image while loading animation corona

Tags: animation, lua, coronasdk

I made a rolling dice with custom animation. [Check out this video to see it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGkcXtV1gH4&feature=youtu.be)

Now you can see while the dice animation begins the previous image stays in the background and replaced after the animation ends. I want to remove the image from background when the animation starts. can anyone say how can I do that?

my main event code here

```
local function listener( event )
if event.phase == "began" then
    audio.play( diceSound )
    dice = display.newImage("images/dice3droll.png")
    physics.addBody(dice, {bounce = 2.8})
    physics.addBody(grass, "static", {bounce = 0.6})
    dice.x = display.contentWidth/2
    dice.y = display.contentHeight/2
    dice.isFocus = true
    dice:scale(2,2)
    display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( dice )
    Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", rotateDice )
    local function timerE(ev)
        rand=math.random(6)
        dice:removeSelf()
        dice.isFocus = false
        dice = display.newImage( "images/dice"..rand..".png" ) 
        dice.x = display.contentWidth/2 
        dice.y = display.contentHeight/2 
        Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", rotateDice )
    end

    timer.performWithDelay( 2000, timerE, 1 )

end 
return true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the original image code, but I'm assuming it's called dice.  When you begin the event, call `display.removeSelf(dice)`.  I would recommend renaming the animation to something other than dice, since it could be mixing up the variables in your code since they are `global` not `local`.